# TimeOut function on Location.getCurrentPositionAsync doesn't timeout

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, expo, settimeout, react-native-maps

I've set my timeout function up for two promises to race until finished (my async function and a timeout function) in order to limit the waiting time for the API call.

It's for an **onFindMe button** on react-native-maps. When the button is clicked it finds the location immediately as designed, but even when I set the Timeout as 1 millisecond it still finds the location and stores it in the currentLoco variable.

I'm using the **Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})** from expo-location to get the location.

Either my timeout function isn't working as designed or its getting the location quicker than 1mls. Is this possible? I'm assuming its my code, in which case please show me the fix!

Timeout Function:

```
export const asyncCallWithTimeout = async (asyncPromise, timeLimit) => {
    let timeoutHandle;

    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_resolve, reject) => {
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(
            () => reject(new Error("Async call timeout limit reached")),
            timeLimit
        );
    });

    return Promise.race([asyncPromise, timeoutPromise]).then((result) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
        return result;
    });
};
```

And here is my snippet for the button

```
const onFindMe = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true);
            let currentLoco = await asyncCallWithTimeout(
                Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({}),
                1
            );
            if (!currentLoco) throw new Error("Timeout when fetching location");
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.log(currentLoco);
        } catch (err) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setError(err);
          
        }
    };
```

Thanks!